# Define forbidden globally slug for all models

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a list of forbidden slug word's for all of my models(product, category ...)
This list contains violent, sexual and irrelevant words.
How can i  do this?

Answer (score 1):

create BaseRequest and extend this on every store, update request. You can create your validator, and use it in your rules:

```
Validator::extend (
            'block_banned_keywords',
            function ( $attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator ) {

                if ( in_array($value,[...]) )
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            ''
        );
```

add this validtior to rules

```
public function rules ()
    {
        $allRequests = request ()->all ();

        $rules = [
            'slug' => 'required|block_banned_keywords'
        ]
        return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create Rule

```
php artisan make:rule BannedKeywordRule
```

modify rule class

```
class BannedKeywordRule implements Rule
{

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return check_banned_keyword($value);
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'Keyword is banned. Please choose another keyword';
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
          'keyword' => ['required', new BannedKeywordRule()]
     ];
}
```